# Getting Android MapView V2 Quick Start Tutorial working

Tags: android, eclipse, maps

I'm trying to follow this guide to get a simple map running: https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=19nQzvKP-CVLd7_VrpwnHfl-AE9fjbJySowONZZtNHzw

I'm getting lost at steps 6 and 8. Where do I put the "GooglePlayServices.util..." line and the "GoogleMap map =" line?

I put them both in the androidmanifest.xml file before the final .

The program runs but it then crashes when I try to open it both in an emulator and on my android device.

Here's my code.

Activity_Main.xml:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
/>
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.mapexample"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<permission android:name="your_package_name.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
     android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<uses-permission  android:name="your_package_name.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <uses-permission    
    android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/>

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.mapexample.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
         android:value="AIzaSyCamZzoe1qpYwpNyqDNpAVw8wlrG1NBd60"/>
GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());
GoogleMap map = ((SupportMapFragment)  
getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
.getMap();
    </application>

</manifest>
```

---

Here's the LogCat:

```
01-30 18:20:17.863: W/Trace(892): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-30 18:20:17.884: W/Trace(892): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-30 18:20:17.884: W/Trace(892): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-30 18:20:18.213: W/Trace(892): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-30 18:20:18.213: W/Trace(892): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-30 18:20:18.733: W/dalvikvm(892): VFY: unable to resolve static field 861   
(MapAttrs) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$styleable;
01-30 18:20:18.733: D/dalvikvm(892): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x000e
01-30 18:20:18.754: D/AndroidRuntime(892): Shutting down VM
01-30 18:20:18.754: W/dalvikvm(892): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught  
exception (group=0x40a70930)
01-30 18:20:18.763: E/AndroidRuntime(892): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-30 18:20:18.763: E/AndroidRuntime(892): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
01-30 18:20:18.763: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at  
com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(Unknown Source)
01-30 18:20:18.763: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at 
com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
01-30 18:20:18.763: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at 
android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:279)
01-30 18:20:18.763: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
01-30 18:20:18.763: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at    
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
01-30 18:20:18.763: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
01-30 18:20:18.763: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at  
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
01-30 18:20:18.763: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at 
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
01-30 18:20:18.763: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at 
android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
01-30 18:20:18.763: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at 
com.example.mapexample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
01-30 18:20:18.763: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at 
android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
01-30 18:20:18.763: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at 
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
01-30 18:20:18.763: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at 
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
01-30 18:20:18.763: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at 
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
01-30 18:20:18.763: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at 
android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-30 18:20:18.763: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at 
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
01-30 18:20:18.763: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-30 18:20:18.763: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-30 18:20:18.763: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at 
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-30 18:20:18.763: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at    
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-30 18:20:18.763: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at   
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-30 18:20:18.763: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-30 18:20:18.763: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-30 18:20:18.763: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native 
Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

The statements cited in steps 6 and 8 are from a programming language, called Java. Java code goes in Java source files, such as those for your activities. Java source code does not go in the manifest.

You do not *need* either of those bits of Java source code. The one from step 6 is generally a good idea, to determine if Maps V2 is available, so you can do something if the user's device cannot display a Maps V2 map. You use the code from step 8 if and when you wish to configure your `GoogleMap` object, such as placing markers on it.

You may wish to consider reading [the Maps V2 documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start) to help supplement the document that you linked to.

Comment: Thanks for dumbing it down for me. I commented out those two lines and I still get "Unfortunately, MapExample has stopped" when I try to run it. Would seeing my logcat be more helpful?

Comment: @user2023615: For crashes, stack traces from LogCat is essential for getting help here on StackOverflow. FWIW, here's my simplest Maps V2 sample project: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MapsV2/Basic

Comment: CommonsWare, so where's the best place to put those two lines? Should they go at the end of MainActivity's onCreate method? I presume since they're setup related they should be called as early as possible in the program's execution. Also, adding those lines requires importing their classes, this is not clear from the description and Eclipse's quick fix options give you more than one way to resolve the problems most of which are not correct. Also, is the onCreateOptionsMenu method still needed?  (Harmless to leave in perhaps, but why leave dead code around if it's not called?)

Comment: @Phil: "so where's the best place to put those two lines?" -- there are more lines required than just those two. For my book examples, I created an `AbstractMapActivity` that isolates the setup code and the required "show the license terms" code: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/MapsV2/Basic/src/com/commonsware/android/mapsv2/basic/AbstractMapActivity.java I then call `readyToGo()` from my subclasses of `AbstractMapActivity` early in `onCreate()`: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/MapsV2/Basic/src/com/commonsware/android/mapsv2/basic/MainActivity.java

Answer (score 0):

I solved this, though I'm not sure exactly how. I think it was because I added this line to my androidmanifest file right before the final /application:

```
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

I also had a couple instances where the code I copy/pasted didn't have my package name in it. I also made sure my package name when I generated my API code was correct.

Comment: FWIW, this did nothing for me :-P

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I got the same error when I went into project settings and added the library in my Java Build Path.
Instead, you have to add the library to the project settings in the Android category on your left (that's an important step in the instructions).

Be sure that the play services library is also on the same drive/partition if you're in Windows as well.  If you don't do this, you'll be able to add it, but when you go look at the library reference in your project again, it'll show up as a red X.